# Is the product/sum of a martingale with a constant still a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

If we have a martingale $M_i$ and some constant $c$, is $cM_i$ also a martingale? I have checked the conditions of a martingale: (1) $\mathbb{E}[|cM_i|] < \infty$ and (2) $\mathbb{E}[cM_{i+1} | cM_i, \dots, cM_1] = \mathbb{E}[cM_{i}]$ (not very sure about this step because of the $c$'s in the conditional) so I am inclined to say it is. I just want some confirmation in case I missed something in my argument and also an explanation of the steps to get the result in (2) if it indeed is.

Also related but I was not able to prove or disprove, would $M_i + c$ be a martingale? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Technically, the process $(M_i)$ is a martingale with respect to some filtration $(\mathcal{F}_i)$, i.e. martingale property is that $\mathbb{E}[M_{i+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_i] = M_i$. Usually the filtration is the canonical filtration, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_i = \sigma(M_j : j \leq i$) is the sigma-algebra (or "information") generated by the sequence so far. So in your case, the canonical filtration of $(c M_i)$ is the same as the original $(M_i)$ -- intuitively, the information generated by the two processes are the same. So for your point (2) to check, you can argue along the lines of $\mathbb{E}[c M_{i+1} \mid c M_1, \dots, c M_i] = c \mathbb{E}[ M_{i+1} \mid c M_1, \dots, c M_i ] = c \mathbb{E}[ M_{i+1} \mid M_1, \dots, M_i ] = c M_i$, for example.

Comment: You can take the $c$ outside the expectation but not the $c's$ in the conditional part. The conditional contains the possible martingale so the c's need to remain.

Comment: As my comment mentions, the (canonical) filtration generated is the same and hence why it is presented as two steps

Comment: I disagree but I guess that's why I got the -1 !!!!! I'm pretty sure that you have to condition so that both sides are the same EXCEPT the LHS is one step ahead. But I'll look around and see if I can find something that supports one of us. I appreciate and understand your explanation. Your saying that, since $c$ is a constan, there is no need to condition on it because, from an information standpoint, it's adds nothing.

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud. Suppose one plays the roulette wheel and the numbers of blacks and reds are equal and he-she bets a dollar each time on red. Then, if we let the total profit of the gambler at time $t$ be $M_t$, then $M_t$ is clearly a martingale. $E(M_{t+1} | M_{t} ) = M_{t}$.

Comment: Now, take the same EXACT game as above but, after the roulette wheel is spun and total profits up to that  point are computed, the weird extra step is that the gambler's current total profits get multiplied by $k$. In this case, if you do the math,  the total profits of the gambler at any time $t$ is not a martingale.